# Run bash script from Debian GNU/Linux

Tags: windows-10, bash, debian, gnu

There are lots of examples on how to run bash scripts on Windows. For example: `bash -c "command"`. I took that example from  https://www.howtogeek.com/261591/how-to-create-and-run-bash-shell-scripts-on-windows-10/

I want to run my bash scripts from Debian though. I have installed this on windows https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/debian-gnulinux-for-wsl-now-available-in-the-windows-store/ . Now I can run bash scripts once I launch that Debian application. **But how I can run a bash script from windows once my computer boots for example?**. I do not want to open the app then manually type `bash /root/someBashScript.sh`. It will be great if I can run it from windows somehow.

### Edit

The reason why I want to run the bash scripts from Debian is because I have arleady installed applications that I need. For example the command `aws s3 sync "/mnt/c/GIT/Foo" s3://someDomain.com/FrontEnd/v1.0/` does not work with the first example. It works great if I open the Debian app then I type that command.

Answer (score 0):

for example I installed `rsync` as `sudo apt-get install rsync` on my debian windows app. I now may execute commands on windows as:   `wsl rsync --help` for example.